# Why doesn't the program wait for the function result?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a program which calls a function "top" to edit some data.  This function uses a number of widgets in a "Toplevel" frame for data adjustment.  When I am through editing, I press and "Exit" button in "top" which calls a routine to return the edited data.

In the main program, I have a "Run" button that I press when it is time to edit the data.  It is then supposed to wait for the result to be returned to print it out, but it does not wait.  If falls through to the print and prints "None".

Why????

```
# Return Test
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def top(parent):

    def doexit():
        return 5

    w = Toplevel(parent)
    mainframe = Frame(w)
    button = Button(w, text="Exit", command=doexit)
    button.pack()

def donew():
    x = print( top(root) )
    print(x)

toolbar = Frame(root, padx=15, pady=15)
toolbar.pack()
button = Button(toolbar, text="Run", command=donew)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It prints None because `top(root)` returns nothing a.k.a `None`.

Comment: I believe that I am explicitly returning 5 which is != nothing.

Comment: Nope. `doexit()` is returning 5. `top()` takes this return value...and does nothing with it. There is no return statement within the definition of `top()` itself.

Comment: So, if there is no "return" in the body of the function, the caller will not wait?  I have to do something like have to button call back set a flag in the main body and have the main body wait for the flag before returning the result?

Comment: You dont get me. You generally dont return values from callbacks; who do u return the value to? The button? its not part of the event-driven programming paradigm. What you do is modify some global variable (a `list` perhaps or an `IntVar`) within the callback and then do what u want with the modified variable when the callback is done with handling the event.

Comment: That worked.  In my actual application, I was taking the returned result and using it to set one of my objects.  I just changed the button callback to set the object directly.  Thank you.